# Cluster analysis on biased binary data

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, binary-data, bias

I have a data set of 86 variables which contains binary and categorical variables.
I have to perform cluster analysis on the same. Also the data set which I have is biased (94% 0 and 6% 1 in dependent variable, where 0 stands for No and 1 stands for Yes). As per my knowledge, cluster analysis can't be performed on binary and categorical data. Can anyone please help me with the same? The dataset is available at the below link (Caravan Insurance data).

https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/caravan-insurance-challenge

Comment: What is dependent variable in a cluster analysis?

Answer (score 1):

It can, you just need to convert the factors into dummy binary 0,1 numerical values and make sure your continuous variables have been standardised. This is essentially one-hot encoding and is used quite often to pass categories into the machine.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good metric it can be used.

It just often does not perform well.

But **if you have a target variable, then do classification, not clustering**.